# I can't understand some parametres

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, triangulation, geometry-surface

i find a paper talk about the camera field of view but i didn't understand the parameter used in the given formula, please i want just to understand the parameter and how that's work. The definition of all things is in the figure.

[image: problem definition]

Comment: Can you be more specific what is not clear to you

Comment: why they use the d_ik vector or what is it role? if i assume that i have only one direction does the formula change?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.